# angular object type unable to return value

Tags: arrays, angular, object

here my en.json

```
{
    "tester1": "return short sentence",
    "tester2": "return very long sentences? bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla",    
    "sure to delete?": "are you sure to delete?",        
    "done.": "deletion completed.",        
}
```

My page got this

```
arrObj : any;
```

I read json file obj into arrObj

```
arrObj = jsonObj;
```

then I try to print result

```
console.log(this.arrObj["tester1"]); //value return
console.log(this.arrObj["tester2"]); //value return
console.log(this.arrObj["sure to delete?"]); //nothing return...
console.log(this.arrObj["done."]); //nothing return...
```

how to make it able to read no matter in what situation?

Comment: You need to remove `?` and `.` in your en.json for that to work. Or add `?` and `.` in your `this.arrObj` key. ex. `this.arrObj["tester3?"]`

Comment: Yeah, that’s not going to work. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: If something is not an array, please do not name it `arrObj`. This will avoid despair.

Comment: Hi simple guy, I modified my question, I actually trying this.arrObj["tester3?"].  It can't return